# GIT run script before git add

Tags: git, bash, git-add

I often require to do a make clean / make distclean before I do a `git add .` since I do not want to include binary and other stuffs.

I know I can add some name / pattern in to `.gitignore` but that's not very productive and flexible. Another solution is to create a bash file but that requires an additional file in my repository that I don't want.

Is there any pre-add configuration that allows me to run script before the actual `git add` execution ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "productive", but `.gitignore` is very flexible.

Comment: for example, the name of the binary may change, or when I add new binary I have to add that into .gitignore too, what's the best way ?

Comment: Modify `gitignore` at the same time you make the change that changes the name of (or introduces) the binary.

Comment: Add `grep -q "^$@$$" .gitignore || echo $@ >>.gitignore` to your makefile's recipe for binaries.

Comment: maybe in pre-commit script you could do what you need and run git add . at the end so commit would work fine with your changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The earliest hook Git provides is the pre-commit hook. At this point, `git add` would already have been run, but you could write a pre-commit hook that ensures certain files / file extensions have not been added. However, this will require the same amount of maintenance as a gitignore file would.

Comment: thanks! could you be clearer about the pre-commit hook ? Is it possible to run a script using that hook ? I can do something like, "git reset; make clean; git add."

Comment: Yes, you can run a script as well as allow or disallow the commit. You can read about Git hooks [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).